# Как добавить изображение в атрибут alt тега img?

Tags: javascript, html

Необходимо в атрибут alt тега img поставить не просто текст, а изображение. Это нужно для реализации эмодзи на сайте. Увидел это на всеми известном vk.com и захотелось узнать, как это можно реализовать, ибо очевидных вариантов на ум не приходит

Конкретный пример кода сайта vk.com:
[image: Пример использования изображения в атрибуте alt тега img]

Comment: Эмодзи является обычным текстом, а не картинкой. Копируйте на здоровье 

Comment: Хм, что-то я, видимо, копировал символ неправильно. Спасибо)